# UIMenuController in iOS 13 beta shows with transparent background instead of black background

Tags: ios13, xcode11, uimenucontroller, uimenuitem

I am using UIMenuController to display custom options. It was working fine with a black background and white text on UIMenuItems till iOS 12.

After upgrading to iOS 13 beta 8 with Xcode 11 beta 7, the background changed to transparent.

Is there anyone else facing this problem?

[image: Incorrect view screenshot]